# Remove password for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, password

I have Google Chrome installed. When I open "Show Applications" and click on the icon for "Google Chrome" I have to enter my password. I built and installed this system and I am the only person ever to use it. I don't want to have to enter a password every time I use Chrome. How can I eliminate this requirement?

Comment: This is a feature of the Chrome application nothing to do with Ubuntu. Look into the chrome settings.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the cancel button 2-3 times when Crome asks the password. it will close the dialog box and you can access Crome without a password.

If you wish to disable permanently do the following steps.

open terminal either via Ctrl+Alt+T or by searching for ‘terminal’ from the application launcher. When it opens, run the command:

sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

Input your password when it prompts and hit enter.

The command opens the launcher file for Google Chrome. All you need is to find out the line starts with Exec and add　a parameter to the value:
--password-store=basic

Save the file and done!